# Launch SharePoint app from Visual Studio takes forever

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint

I'm trying to develop a SharePoint Application using the default template Visual Studio provides for C# using MVC, but whenever I try to launch it, it compiles everything without any error but it takes forever in the following step:

```
Installation is in progress (00:26:51)
Installation is in progress (00:26:52)
...
```

Already 26 minutes and counting...

Looking at the SharePoint site it displays the app I've just created with the following message:

> SharePointApp1
>
> We're adding your app, click here to cancel.

Any clue why this is taking so long?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint? Is it an App for SharePoint (using CSOM) or a farm solution (WSP)?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to create the SharePoint App for SharePoint 2013.
I've selected from the template the "Provider-hosted" option.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?